# MySQL Question: It is possible to return more than one column in a function?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 DELIMITER //

       CREATE FUNCTION retur1(NR int)
    RETURNS INT
    DETERMINISTIC
        BEGIN
        DECLARE ManagerList VARCHAR(50);
        SELECT CodP INTO ManagerList FROM FPa WHERE ID = NR;
        RETURN ManagerList;
        END;

//
DELIMITER ;
```

This is my function, I have no problems, it extracts strictly integer data from the table, but I am wondering if it is possible to extract two columns from a single call. I mean, if I introduce a column that has names in it, I could generate a result like this?

|Name | Integer|

I understand that MySQL returns only one result from the table, but I would like to know if there is a way. Thanks.

EXEMPE:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4mSW.png

Comment: no, if you want to return two values, you should use a stored procedure with two OUT parameters.  but you might get a better answer if you showed how you want to *use* the values returned.

Comment: yes, I know that only with create procedure can I extract more data, I was just curious if it is possible to make a function that calls a single row from several columns simultaneously. Or a function that calls a procedure that does this. If it's posibile, but I don't think so, thank you for the answer.

Comment: you can do a select that reads multiple columns into variables at once, if that's what you are asking.  when you say things like "calls a single row" I have no idea what you mean; showing examples might be helpful.

Comment: Mysql does not have a ro or table as a return type, so no, a function cam onky return a single value.

Comment: @ysth I posted an image as an example, that's what I'm thinking. When, for example, I call ID 1, I can generate two columns, each with a single result on it. Example: Christian| 24562

Comment: yes, but what are you doing with those two values?  using them in a query?  returning them to the client?